# Capacitor configs for ios simulator don't work on a physical devise

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm using [Capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com/) to build a native app using Vue.js. I'm still figuring out the development environment and workflow. I am trying to figure out a configuration that will work on the ios simulator AND building on an actual ios devise.

I can get live reloading to work in the simulator, using the following configs:

```
import { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'com.example.my_app',
  appName: 'My App',
  webDir: 'dist',
  server: {
    androidScheme: 'https',
    url: 'http://localhost:5173/',
    cleartext: true
  }
};

export default config;
```

But when I try to build the app on my actual iphone, I get a blank white screen and this error in Xcode:

```
⚡️  WebView failed provisional navigation
⚡️  Error: Could not connect to the server.
```

I also see in the Xcode logs that the app is trying to connect to my local dev server. So I remove two lines and this works to build on my iPhone:

```
import { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'com.example.my_app',
  appName: 'My App',
  webDir: 'dist',
  server: {
    androidScheme: 'https',
    // url: 'http://localhost:5173/',
    // cleartext: true
  }
};

export default config;
```

...but with these configs live reloading does not work on the simulator.

How do I configure it so that I can build on a physical devise AND develop with live reloading on the simulator:

Answer (score 0):

<s>Solved!</s>

I was missing two things:

1. The local dev server has to be set to the ip: `0.0.0.0`. With Vue3/Vite it meant changing the script in package.json to...

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --host 0.0.0.0",
```

2. The vite configs need to set the server to the ip address on the network

Now the app builds successfully and live reloads on the simulator, a real device, and the web browser.

```
import { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'com.example.my_app',
  appName: 'My App',
  webDir: 'dist',
  server: {
    androidScheme: 'https',
    url: 'http://192.168.x.xx:5173',
    cleartext: true
  }
};

export default config;
```

### UPDATE

The following solution has an annoying gotcha! If you build the app with these settings, the app will only work on the local network with your dev server running. You can comment out the `url: http://...` in the configs and then the build will work normally, but this is annoying and clunky.